# Get Queue Size in Pika (AMQP Python)

Tags: python, amqp

Simple question, but Google or the Pika open source code did not help. Is there a way to query the current queue size (item counter) in Pika?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to get the queue size in the AMQP protocol. You can either use Queue.Declare or Basic.Get.

If you are consuming messages as they arrive using Basic.Consume, then you can't get this info unless you disconnect (timeout) and redeclare the queue, or else get one message but don't ack it. In newer versions of AMQP you can actively requeue the message.

As for Pika, I don't know the specifics but Python clients for AMQP have been a thorn in my side. Often you will need to monkeypatch classes in order to get the info you need, or to allow a queue consumer to timeout so that you can do other things at periodic intervals like record stats or find out how many messages are in a queue.

Another way around this is to give up, and use the Pipe class to run `sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues -p my_vhost`. Then parse the output to find the size of all queues. If you do this you will need to configure `/etc/sudoers` to not ask for the usual sudo password.

I pray that someone else with more Pika experience answers this by pointing out how you can do all the things that I mentioned, in which case I will download Pika and kick the tires. But if that doesn't happen and you are having difficulty with monkeypatching the Pika code, then have a look at `haigha`. I found their code to be much more straightforward than other Python AMQP client libraries because they stick closer to the AMQP protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues -p my_vhost trick, I will try that.

Answer (score 53):

I know that this question is a bit old, but here is an example of doing this with pika.

Regarding AMQP and RabbitMQ, if you have already declared the queue, you can re-declare the queue with the [passive flag](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.declare.passive) on and keeping all other queue parameters identical. The response to this declaration [declare-ok](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.declare-ok) will include the number of messages in the queue.

Here is an example With pika 0.9.5:

```
import pika

def on_callback(msg):
    print msg

params = pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='localhost',
        port=5672,
        credentials=pika.credentials.PlainCredentials('guest', 'guest'),
    )

# Open a connection to RabbitMQ on localhost using all default parameters
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters=params)

# Open the channel
channel = connection.channel()

# Declare the queue
channel.queue_declare(
        callback=on_callback,
        queue="test",
        durable=True,
        exclusive=False,
        auto_delete=False
    )

# ...

# Re-declare the queue with passive flag
res = channel.queue_declare(
        callback=on_callback,
        queue="test",
        durable=True,
        exclusive=False,
        auto_delete=False,
        passive=True
    )
print 'Messages in queue %d' % res.method.message_count
```

This will print the following:

```
<Method(['frame_type=1', 'channel_number=1', "method=<Queue.DeclareOk(['queue=test', 'message_count=0', 'consumer_count=0'])>"])>
<Method(['frame_type=1', 'channel_number=1', "method=<Queue.DeclareOk(['queue=test', 'message_count=0', 'consumer_count=0'])>"])>
Messages in queue 0
```

You get the number of messages from the `message_count` member.

Comment: Just leaving this here because it bit me and cost me a couple of hours. It's important to understand that this is only the "true" number of messages if the consumers haven't prefetched too many messages. Refer to https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/channel.html#pika.channel.Channel.basic_qos for the `prefetch_count`.

Comment: As accepted answer mentions, doesn't work when basic_consume, for instance, is already initiated, it will just show message_count=0 even though there may be many.

Answer (score 25):

Here is how you can get queue length using pika(Considering you are using default user and password on localhost)
replace q_name by your queue name.

```
import pika
connection = pika.BlockingConnection()
channel = connection.channel()
q = channel.queue_declare(q_name)
q_len = q.method.message_count
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried [PyRabbit](http://pyrabbit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)? It has a `get_queue_depth()` [method](http://pyrabbit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#pyrabbit.api.Client.get_queue_depth) which sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: I didn’t know PyRabbit. Looks promising, I will try it out!

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party but this is an example getting queue count using [pyrabbit](https://github.com/bkjones/pyrabbit) or [pyrabbit2](https://github.com/deslum/pyrabbit2) from AWS AmazonMQ with HTTPS, should work on RabbitMQ as well:

```
from pyrabbit2.api import Client

cl = Client('b-xxxxxx.mq.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com', 'user', 'password', scheme='https')
if not cl.is_alive():
    raise Exception("Failed to connect to rabbitmq")

for i in cl.get_all_vhosts():
    print(i['name'])

queues = [q['name'] for q in cl.get_queues('/')]
print(queues)    

itemCount = cl.get_queue_depth('/', 'event.stream.my-api')
print(itemCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this in case anyone else comes across this discussion. The answer with the most votes, i.e.:

```
# Re-declare the queue with passive flag
res = channel.queue_declare(
        callback=on_callback,
        queue="test",
        durable=True,
        exclusive=False,
        auto_delete=False,
        passive=True
    )
```

was very helpful for me, but it comes with a serious caveat. According to the pika documentation, the `passive` flag is used to "Only check to see if the queue exists." As such, one would imagine you can use the queue_declare function with the `passive` flag to check if a queue exists in situations where there's a chance that the queue was never declared. From my testing, if you call this function with the `passive` flag and the queue does not exist, not only does the api throw an exception; it will also cause the broker to disconnect your channel, so even if you catch the exception gracefully, you've lost your connection to the broker. I tested this with 2 different python scripts against a plain vanilla RabbitMQ container running in minikube. I've run this test many times and I get the same behavior every time.

My test code:

```
import logging
import pika

logging.basicConfig(level="INFO")
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.getLogger("pika").setLevel(logging.WARNING)


def on_callback(msg):
    logger.info(f"Callback msg: {msg}")


queue_name = "testy"

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials("guest", "guest")

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host="localhost", port=5672, credentials=credentials)
)

logger.info("Connection established")

channel = connection.channel()

logger.info("Channel created")

channel.exchange_declare(exchange="svc-exchange", exchange_type="direct", durable=True)

response = channel.queue_declare(
    queue=queue_name, durable=True, exclusive=False, auto_delete=False, passive=True
)

logger.info(f"queue_declare response: {response}")

channel.queue_delete(queue=queue_name)

connection.close()
```

The output:

```
INFO:__main__:Connection established
INFO:__main__:Channel created
WARNING:pika.channel:Received remote Channel.Close (404): "NOT_FOUND - no queue 'testy' in vhost '/'" on <Channel number=1 OPEN conn=<SelectConnection OPEN transport=<pika.adapters.utils.io_services_utils._AsyncPlaintextTransport object at 0x1047e2700> params=<ConnectionParameters host=localhost port=5672 virtual_host=/ ssl=False>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check_queue_len.py", line 29, in <module>
    response = channel.queue_declare(
  File "/Users/dbailey/dev/asc-service-deployment/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 2521, in queue_declare
    self._flush_output(declare_ok_result.is_ready)
  File "/Users/dbailey/dev/asc-service-deployment/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1354, in _flush_output
    raise self._closing_reason  # pylint: disable=E0702
pika.exceptions.ChannelClosedByBroker: (404, "NOT_FOUND - no queue 'testy' in vhost '/'")
```

When I set `passive` to False:

```
scripts % python check_queue_len.py
INFO:__main__:Connection established
INFO:__main__:Channel created
INFO:__main__:queue_declare response: <METHOD(['channel_number=1', 'frame_type=1', "method=<Queue.DeclareOk(['consumer_count=0', 'message_count=0', 'queue=testy'])>"])>
```

Please let me know if I'm somehow missing something here.