# Polling for RabbitMQ messages using Pika client

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am wanting to create a RabbitMQ receiver/consumer in Python and am not sure how to check for messages.  I am trying to do this in my own loop, not using the call-backs in pika.

If I understand things, in the Java client I can use `getBasic()` to check to see if there are any messages available without blocking.  I don't mind blocking while getting messages, but I don't want to block until there is a message.

I don't find any clear examples and haven't yet figured out the corresponding call in pika.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it synchronously then you will need to look at the pika `BlockingConnection`

> The BlockingConnection creates a layer on top of Pika’s asynchronous
>   core providng methods that will block until their expected response
>   has returned. Due to the asynchronous nature of the Basic.Deliver and
>   Basic.Return calls from RabbitMQ to your application, you are still
>   required to implement continuation-passing style asynchronous methods
>   if you’d like to receive messages from RabbitMQ using basic_consume or
>   if you want to be notified of a delivery failure when using
>   basic_publish.

More info and an example here

https://pika.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.12/connecting.html#blockingconnection

Answer (score 1):

You can periodically check the queue size using the example of this answer [Get Queue Size in Pika (AMQP Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192584/get-queue-size-in-pika-amqp-python/13629296#13629296)

Comment: It seems that `queue.method.message_count` is only updated on a `queue_declare()` call.
While there's also `get_waiting_message_count()`, it always returns 0 when used without a consume loop.
Thus, calling `queue_declare()` multiple times seems to be the only solution still compatible to the API.

Comment: Found `process_data_events()` from the API as well.

Comment: This is correct. You must execute the passive queue declaration in order to get the current message count.

Answer (score 1):

Queue processing loop can be done iteratively with the help of `process_data_events()`:

```
import pika

# A stubborn callback that still wants to be in the code.
def mq_callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" Received: %r" % body)

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters("localhost"))
channel = connection.channel()
queue_state = channel.queue_declare(queue="test")
# Configure a callback.
channel.basic_consume(mq_callback, queue="test")

try:
    # My own loop here:
    while(True):
        # Do other processing

        # Process message queue events, returning as soon as possible.
        # Issues mq_callback() when applicable.
        connection.process_data_events(time_limit=0)
finally:
    connection.close()
```