# Getting number of messages in a RabbitMQ queue

Tags: python, rabbitmq, message-queue, py-amqplib

We're using [amqplib](http://barryp.org/software/py-amqplib/) to publish/consume messages. I want to be able to read the number of messages on a queue (ideally both acknowledged and unacknowledged). This will allow me to show a nice status diagram to the admin users and detect if a certain component is not keeping up with the load.

I can't find any information in the amqplib docs about reading queue status.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192584/get-queue-size-in-pika-amqp-python/13629296#13629296

Comment: Thanks @mike, that's largely what I ended up doing when I had to reimplement some of this in C#. For the Python approach, I ended up hitting the rabbitmq-admin plugin and querying that instead. In any case, I appreciate the pointer.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**Using pika:**

```
import pika

pika_conn_params = pika.ConnectionParameters(
    host='localhost', port=5672,
    credentials=pika.credentials.PlainCredentials('guest', 'guest'),
)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika_conn_params)
channel = connection.channel()
queue = channel.queue_declare(
    queue="your_queue", durable=True,
    exclusive=False, auto_delete=False
)

print(queue.method.message_count)
```

**Using PyRabbit:**

```
from pyrabbit.api import Client
cl = Client('localhost:55672', 'guest', 'guest')
cl.get_messages('example_vhost', 'example_queue')[0]['message_count']
```

**Using HTTP**

Syntax:

```
curl -i -u user:password http://localhost:15672/api/queues/vhost/queue
```

Example:

```
curl -i -u guest:guest http://localhost:15672/api/queues/%2f/celery
```

Note: Default vhost is `/` which needs to be escaped as `%2f`

**Using CLI:**

```
$ sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues | grep 'my_queue'
```

Comment: The `PyRabbit` solution retrieves a message from the queue. I think you want to use `cl.get_queue("example_vhost", "example_queue")['messages']` instead.

Comment: How would you get the number of unack'd messages in a queue?

Comment: For pika: Just leaving this here because it bit me and cost me a couple of hours. It's important to understand that this is only the "true" number of messages if the consumers haven't prefetched too many messages. Refer to https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/channel.html#pika.channel.Channel.basic_qos for the `prefetch_count`.

Comment: I believe queue declare with pika should be done this way:
`queue = channel.queue_declare(queue="your_queue", passive=True)`

This won't fail if say, the durable value of your declare statement mismatches that of the currently existing queue.

Answer (score 8):

following the answer of ChillarAnand you can get the value easily. the data is in the object.

```
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
            host='localhost',
            port=5672,
            credentials=pika.credentials.PlainCredentials('guest', 'guest'),
        )
channel = connection.channel()
print(channel.queue_declare(queue="your_queue", durable=True,  exclusive=False,
                  auto_delete=False).method.message_count)
```

and you will get the exact message number

Comment: Why did you just copy Chillar's answer over a year later?

Comment: It was a different answer when i answered. look at the edit log...

Answer (score 3):

Using the Java API, you can do the following :

```
channel.queueDeclarePassive(queueName).getMessageCount()
```

I believe this is also available with amqplib (according to https://code.google.com/p/py-amqplib/source/browse/amqplib/client_0_8/channel.py#1356 it seems that `queue_declare()` returns a tuple with the message count)

If you need more precise metrics (especially nack message count), you need to use rabbitmqctl or rabbitmq_management. Rabbitmq_management is probably a good choice due to its HTTP API. More info : http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

Comment: "Q: Using Python how to I..." - "A: Using Java you do..." -> -1

Comment: as of today, `Python` is not mentioned in the OP

Comment: amqplib is a python library and the question _is_ tagged Python  but I agree I could've been a lot clearer, so apologies for the confusion