# celery: how to count total number of messages in a queue every interval?

Tags: python, celery

I want to monitor a queue to be notified when it becomes empty. To do this I need to find out how many messages are in the queue and this task needs to run every interval ex. every 15 seconds.

I am confused reading the docs which say that you shouldn't use celerybeat in a worker for production, so does this mean I need to create a separate python script that utilizes periodic tasks? Not sure how I can implement this.

Comment: Just run beat in another process: `$ celery beat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve number of messages in a queue using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27074594/2698552).

For beat, you can always start a new process using

```
celery beat
```

If you don't want to use beat at all, you can schedule a cron job which will do that for you.

Comment: say im using pyrabbit, how would i tell celery beat to run this every 30 seconds?

Comment: run a periodic task http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries

Comment: where do I put CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE , in the same script as the one my workers are using? wouldn't that create multiple schedules? or does only the worker with `-B` option run that every interval? if a worker doesn't have -B specified, it will ignore it?

Comment: this(https://gist.github.com/ChillarAnand/f660e18ca4a4c13a8645) is my periodic tasks and i run worker with `celery beat -A periodic_task`