# Why does celery.control.inspect report fewer queued tasks than rabbitmqctl?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, rabbitmqctl

`rabbitmqctl` correctly reports thousands of queued tasks:

```
$ sudo rabbitmqctl -q list_queues name messages messages_ready messages_unacknowledged
default 13142   13126   16
```

Yet celery reports:

```
>>> len(app.control.inspect().active()['celery@default'])
4
>>> len(app.control.inspect().scheduled()['celery@default'])
1
>>> len(app.control.inspect().reserved()['celery@default'])
16
>>> len(app.control.inspect().revoked()['celery@default'])
0
```

The correct number (thousands) of tasks seem to show up in `app.control.inspect().stats()['celery@default']['total']`, but I really want to know the correct number of *outstanding* queued tasks from within python, and `active()` et al seem to only ever report up to 16 or so -- perhaps there is a limit?

Short of using privileged subprocess calls to `rabbitmqctl`, how can I get the full queued task count from within python, preferably via `celery` (btw this server is using Celery 3.1.8 currently)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Celery's [app.control.inspect](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#inspecting-workers) will inspect tasks that are handled **only by running workers**.

Even though you have thousands of tasks in queue, your worker will execute only few specified tasks at any given point of time. These are `active` tasks.

In addition to that, a worker can prefetch some tasks which will be reserved for that worker. These will be shown in `reserved` tasks.

If you have set ETA for your tasks or if there are periodic tasks, they will come under `scheduled` tasks.

Looks like you have started a worker with concurrency of 4 (or worker with default settings on a 4 core machine). So active tasks are 4. Each worker process has prefetched 4 tasks, which resulted in 16 reserved tasks.

AFAIK, there is no way to get total count of tasks in queue with celery.

However there are several python solutions to get total count of messages in queue.  You can check [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27074594/2698552) for other ways to do this.

Update:

`pika` is a python client to interact with rabbitmq. You can use it to consume messages. Here is a [simple example to consume](https://github.com/ChillarAnand/01/blob/master/python/pika_exp.py) each message. You can checkout more [usage examples](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/examples.html) on pika docs.

Comment: Thank you! Can I also get details of what each message on the queue is using `pika` etc, or just the total number of messages in the queue?

Comment: Thanks @ChillarAnand; does "consuming" messages via `pika` leave them safely on the queue for celery to process? If so, this is a good solution

Comment: @DrMeers I don't think there is a way for that. However you can consume and requeue  messages http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/How-to-get-the-list-of-messages-from-Queue-without-consuming-the-messages-td28135.html