# correct way to constantly get count of queue in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, queue

Please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691161/getting-number-of-messages-in-a-rabbitmq-queue)
it describes a way to get the number of messages in the queue , but it can only be done once ! in this example , you cannot use a loop while to constantly know the number of messages - is there a way to know the number of messages constantly . You can see for yourself and request `queue.method.message_count` after each receipt - and you will always receive the same value! Please do not put a minus if it seemed to you that my question is stupid ! We are all learning !

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct way, you are doing it wrong... statistics are only updated every 5 seconds through the management api and should not be used as runtimes metrics. Getting the counts of messages directly from the queues constantly is an expensive operation.