# Pika: how to consume messages synchronously

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I would like to run a process periodically(like once per 10 minutes, or once per hour) that gets all the messages from queue, processes them and then exits. Is there any way to do this with `pika` or should I use a different python lib?

Comment: How about running a python script with cron every 10 minutes?

Comment: Yes, this is the idea. The problem is getting all messages, processing them and then exiting(not running indefinitely).

Comment: If new messages arrive while the script is running, do you prefer processing them on the same go, or postponing until next time?

Comment: Either way is fine, I would prefer simpler solution(i.e. less code)

Answer (score 9):

I think an ideal solution here would be to use the [basic_get](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html#basic.get) method. It will fetch a single message, but if the the queue is already empty it will return `None`. The advantage of this is that you can clear the queue with a simple loop, and then simply break the loop once `None` is returned, plus it is safe to run basic_get with multiple consumers.

This example is based on *my own* library; [amqpstorm](https://github.com/eandersson/amqpstorm), but you could easily implement the same with [pika](https://github.com/pika/pika) as well.

```
from amqpstorm import Connection

connection = Connection('127.0.0.1', 'guest', 'guest')
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue.declare('simple_queue')
while True:
    result = channel.basic.get(queue='simple_queue', no_ack=False)
    if not result:
        print("Channel Empty.")
        # We are done, lets break the loop and stop the application.
        break
    print("Message:", result['body'])
    channel.basic.ack(result['method']['delivery_tag'])
channel.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: Minor fix: the result is not a dict, so in order to process the result as dict we should work as follows: json.loads(result.body)

Comment: Changes required for pika are: `basic.get/nack` -> `basic_get/nack` (note the underscore). Pika `basic_get` directly returns a tuple `(method, properties, body)` which are all `None` if there is no message. Parameter `no_ack` is named `auto_ack`. Use `method.delivery_tag` for argument of  `basic_ack`.

Answer (score 3):

Would this work for you:

1. Measure the current queue length as `N = queue.method.message_count`
2. Make the callback count the processed messages and as soon as `N` are processed, call `channel.stop_consuming`.

So, client code would be something like this:

```
class CountCallback(object):
    def __init__(self, count):
        self.count = count

    def __call__(self, ch, method, properties, body):
        # process the message here
        self.count -= 1
        if not self.count:
            ch.stop_consuming()

channel = conn.channel()
queue = channel.queue_declare('tasks')
callback = CountCallback(queue.method.message_count)
channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='tasks')
channel.start_consuming()
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like almost what I want. But if I understand correctly, I can't run two copies of this program simultaneously. Does queue.method.message_count gets updated every time message is consumed? Can I check this variable in callback?

Comment: I don't plan to run two copies of the program, but I'd like to add support just in case it gets run twice accidentally

Comment: @AlexanderPutilin as far as I understand, `message_count` is a part of response to AMQP [`queue.declare`](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.declare), and I failed to do so from the consuming callback. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8193456/770830) may shed some light.

Comment: I would not recommend this approach, or at the very least you should be continuously checking the status of the queue. If message acknowledgement is disabled, this would cause all unhandled messages to be permanently lost. Since when stop_consuming is called, anything still in the buffer will be whiped (and lost). Meaning that any additional messages added to the queue after queue_declared was called would be lost.

Answer (score 1):

[@eandersson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/408182/eandersson)

> This example is based on my own library; amqpstorm, but you could easily implement the same with pika as well.

updated for amqpstorm 2.6.1 :

```python
from amqpstorm import Connection

connection = Connection('127.0.0.1', 'guest', 'guest')
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue.declare('simple_queue')
while True:
    result = channel.basic.get(queue='simple_queue', no_ack=False)
    if not result:
        print("Channel Empty.")
        # We are done, lets break the loop and stop the application.
        break
    print("Message:", result.body)
    channel.basic.ack(result.method['delivery_tag'])
channel.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. It fixed some of the issues that was provided in one of the other answers in this thread.